# Conditional set_fact only with selectattr?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use set_fact, but only when an item is defined. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

Playbook:

```
---
  - hosts: localhost

    vars:
      apps:
        - name: app1
          role: "app1-role"
        - name: app2
          role: "app2-role"
        - name: app4
          role: "app4-role"

    tasks:
    - name: "Find a matching app, and print the values"
      set_fact:
        app: "{{ apps | selectattr('name', 'match', app_name) | first }}"
```

The task fails when there is no match, for example: `app_name=app3`, with this message:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: No first item, sequence was empty.

I have tried a few different conditionals, but I'm not quite sure how to structure this.

```
      when: (apps | selectattr('name', 'match', app_name)) is undefined
```

This condition always evaluates as False - `skipping: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this :

```
when: "{{ apps | selectattr('name', 'match', app_name) | list }}"
```

It seems that without the `list` filter, `selectattr` returning a generator object does not seem to allow converting to a boolean for the test evaluation. I'm not 100% sure about this interpretation though.

Note that having `is defined` or not would not change anything, it would be totally equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting used to wrapping my head around using these filters. I had sort of figured the same thing about the generator object - using debug output.  So by adding the list filter, we get an intrinsic boolean - allowing the `when` to evaluate undefined or defined?

Comment: I got a warning when running with the jinja2 template delimiters: ` [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{ apps | selectattr('name', 'match', app_name) |
list }}`. Removing the quotes and curly braces seems to be the preferred syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
      - set_fact:
          app: "{{ mylist|first }}"
        vars:
          mylist: "{{ apps|selectattr('name', 'match', app_name)|list }}"
        when: mylist|length > 0
```

Next option is *`json_query`* instead of *`selectattr`*

```
      - set_fact:
          app: "{{ mylist|first }}"
        vars:
          query: "[?name=='{{ app_name }}']"
          mylist: "{{ apps|json_query(query) }}"
        when: mylist|length > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The first option doesn't appear to work, having a similar issue that the generator returned from the `selectattr`  doesn't have a length: `object of type 'generator' has no len()`

Comment: The jquery approach works as well. I think I will use the `list` filter as it is a simpler option, but this jquery may be a handy tool for another case. Thanks!

Comment: Right. json_query is more robust. It always returns a  list.